# "session-factory" must match "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)"

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory, hibernate.cfg.xml

I can't find what's wrong with my hibernate.cfg.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
- <!--  Database connection settings 
  --> 
  <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property> 
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2://localhost:1527/hibernatedb</property> 
  <property name="connection.username">h2</property> 
  <property name="connection.password" /> 
- <!--  JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) 
  --> 
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property> 

- <!--  Disable the second-level cache  
  --> 
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.CollectionCacheInvalidator
  </property> 
- <!--  Echo all executed SQL to stdout 
  --> 
  <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
- <!--  Drop and re-create the database schema on startup 
  --> 
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 

  - <!--  SQL dialect 
  --> 
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

- <!--  Names the annotated entity class 
  --> 
  <mapping class="firsthibernateproj.UserDetails" />

  </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is the class that I use:

```
    public class HibernateTest {
    private static Object configuration;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("First User");

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
        applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build()); 


        Session session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

xml file was checked, there no grammar mistakes.

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are those `-` chars before every comment really in the code, or it's some formatting typo?

Comment: show your stacktrace

Comment: - chars are in the code

Comment: Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 59; columnNumber: 21; The content of element type "session-factory" must match "(property*,mapping*,(class-cache|collection-cache)*,event*,listener*)".

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration

Comment: There is a probability you have copied from some source, just maintain tab spaces correctly and you're good to go!

Answer (score 5):

This problem occurs when you don't make the configuration file in order 
first list property then mapping and finally cache.

Answer (score 1):

Your file copied to my project also reports the same error, but the error goes away when those `-` characters before every comment are removed. Did you copy the content from some app that formats the xml? e.g. Internet Explorer does that

**EDIT** :)

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <!--  Database connection settings 
  --> 
  <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property> 
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2://localhost:1527/hibernatedb</property> 
  <property name="connection.username">h2</property> 
  <property name="connection.password" /> 
  <!--  JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) 
  --> 
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property> 

  <!--  Disable the second-level cache  
  --> 
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.CollectionCacheInvalidator
  </property> 
  <!--  Echo all executed SQL to stdout 
  --> 
  <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
  <!--  Drop and re-create the database schema on startup 
  --> 
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> 

  <!--  SQL dialect 
  --> 
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

  <!--  Names the annotated entity class 
  --> 
  <mapping class="firsthibernateproj.UserDetails" />

  </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: in this case another problem appears 
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: 
Error while creating file "//" [90062-181]

Comment: That is unrelated to this question, h2 driver configuration probably.

Answer (score 1):

I had passed from same problem.But i have been solved this by just arranging all xml tag in a sequence ..

Answer (score 0):

This problem occures if you copy sourcecode from the internet with a wrong (i.e. not matching the encoding of the target-file) encoding. If your overwrite EVERY single whitespace, line return, every character - EVERYTHING by hand, your file will work.

Alternatively you can also paste the code into an "stupid" editor, mark all and copy again. That could do the trick, too (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same eror. After searching and redeploying for about an hour. It turned out that i mistakinly typed a 'Q' somewhere in the configuration file and could not see it.
So check your file closely, you must have misspelled something or typed some characters.

Answer (score 0):

I too had faced the same error once. I found out that I wrote a description line in hibernate.cfg.xml and i did not 'comment' that down.

it seems u also made the same mistake. I see an additional hyphen before every comment in your conf file.

"

```
- <!--  JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) 
  -->
```

"

it should be "

```
<!--  JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) 
  -->
```

"

that's the only mistake i guess